# Re-using DataReader for another connection

Tags: c#, sql, dao, sqldatareader, datareader

My task is to save the state of `DataReader` for another connection to the same base.

I have got many tables in my database. One of them is always read-only, another are allowed to modify. I would like to create `DataReader` which will be re-open on recent position after opening the same connection. I need to modify other tables in way depending on read-only table content and every time my searching would be start from recent row.

My read-only table is really big and using `DataReader` makes my program much incomparably faster. I'm looking for solutions for `SQL Server`, `DAO` and `Oracle`.

EDIT: In fact it could be still the same connection, but I need to read and write to different tables alternately.

Comment: put the contents of your data reader into data table and use the data table

Comment: As I said: my read-only table is really big. It could has size of many gigabytes. It is unacceptable to store it in RAM.

Comment: Is one connection for reading, the other for writing an option? You could leave the read connection and its datareader open.

Comment: C.Eveinhuis: As the SQLServer and Oracle supports more than one connection, DAO doesn't. SQLServer and Oracle are often is running on better machines, so saving memory isn't so crucial. It doesn't solve problem for DAO connections.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the connection is open and the datareader did not reach the last row of the executed query, the DataReader.Read() will fetch the next row. But when the connection closes, the underlying datareader will be closed as well, hence, you will need to execute the query again, and you will start the iteration on row 1.

One possible method to achieve your need is to create a boolean field in your table that indicates the cursor position. Then adjust your query to start with the row that has this field set to true.

Comment: To add to your answer, if that table has an incremental Id (or datetime) you could just add `WHERE Id > @last_id` to consecutive `SELECT`s, preventing the need to run through already processed records.